# Declare a varible or property as "BaseClassType" and also require it to implement an interface?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, inheritance

Is it possible in vb.net to declare a member variable or property to be some derived class that also happens to implement a interface? By that I mean given:

```
Class Shape
    ...
End class

Class Cube
    Inherits Shape
    ...
End Class

Class Sphere
    Inherits Shape
    Implements IRollable
    ...
End Class

Class Cylinder
    Inherits Shape
    Implements IRollable
    ...
End Class
```

Can I declare a Property or "class level variable"(do these have a specific name in vb.net) that is ether a Shape (Sphere or a Cylinder) but not a Cube?

```
'This is what I want to do
Class A
    Dim roller1 as Shape And IRollable
    'Or
    Property roller2 (Of RollingShape) as {Shape, IRollable}
End Class
```

If such a thing is not possible is there an architectural reason why ether in vb.net or the .net framework?

I suppose I could do this empty class and make both the other class inherit it but that seems messy and ugly:

```
Class RollableShape
    Inherits Shape
    Implements IRollable
End Class
```

Comment: `ISpherical` which  Implements `IRollable` which Cube does not implement.  I would leave `Shape` as a Type if there were commonalities shared by Sphere and Cube.  RollableShape could inherit from shape and implement ISpherical and by extension, IRollable (which might now be a synonym)

Comment: According to your own requirements, the `RollableShape` class idea appears to be what's needed.  I guess you'd want to make sure it's an abstract class (`MustInherit`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about defining an IShape interface and having IRollable derive from that?

```
Interface IShape
...
End Interface

Interface IRollable Inherits IShape
...
End Interface

Class Shape Implements IShape
...
End Class

Class Sphere Inherits Shape Implements IRollable
...
End Class

Class A
  Dim roller As IRollable
End Class
```

This way A only ever depends on the interfaces like IShape and IRollable.